# ListViewItem check by user, not by program

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have a `ListView` with various items and a `ItemCheck` handler as below:

```
private void ListView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.NewValue == System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked)
        {
            if (e.Index == 0)
            {
                ListView1.Items[1].Checked = false;
                ListView1.Items[2].Checked = false;
                ListView1.Items[3].Checked = false;
                ListView1.Items[4].Checked = false;
                ListView1.Items[5].Checked = false;
                ListView1.Items[6].Checked = false;
                ListView1.Items[7].Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ListView1.Items[0].Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially the first item is "none", so when it is checked all the other items become unchecked (and vice-versa). Occasionally the program checks items in the code and I think this is causing problems. I know `TreeViewEventArgs` has a field called `Action` which is equal to `TreeViewAction.Unkown`if the call is coming from the program and not from the user.

Is there a way to check if a `ListViewItem` is being checked by a user as opposed to being checked by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to tell from the event arguments so you would have code for it yourself, something like

```
        private bool raisedFromCode;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        raisedFromCode = true;
        listView1.Items[1].Checked = !listView1.Items[1].Checked;
        raisedFromCode = false;
    }

    private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs args)
    {

        if (!raisedFromCode)
            MessageBox.Show("User checked");

    }
```

Alternatively if you just don't want your logic to fire when you change the check state through code you could unsubscribe from the event handler

```
        listView1.ItemCheck -= new ItemCheckEventHandler(this.listView1_ItemCheck);
        listView1.Items[1].Checked = false;
        listView1.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(this.listView1_ItemCheck);
```